# OneDrive reporting - getOneDriveUsageAccountDetail not working for the period param but working for the date param

Tags: microsoft-graph-api

Calling this API with period param
[https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/reports/getOneDriveUsageAccountDetail(period='D30')?$format=application%2fjson](https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/reports/getOneDriveUsageAccountDetail(period=%27D30%27)?$format=application%2fjson)
returns empty array

```
{
    "@odata.context": "https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/$metadata#Collection(oneDriveUsageAccountDetail)",
    "value": []
}
```

Calling the same API with date param works
https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/reports/getOneDriveUsageAccountDetail(date=2020-10-05)?$format=application/json

```
{
    "@odata.context": "https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/$metadata#Collection(oneDriveUsageAccountDetail)",
    "@odata.nextLink": "https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/reports/getOneDriveUsageAccountDetail(date=2020-10-05)?$format=application%2fjson%0a&$skiptoken=MDoyOg",
    "value": [
        ...
    ]
}
```

API doc: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/reportroot-getonedriveusageaccountdetail?view=graph-rest-beta

Comment: unfortunately i failed to repro the issue - it works for me :)

Comment: Yeah, It works for me too!!

Comment: I have tried again - still nothing.
Other reporting APIs for OneDrive are working with both period and date. SharePoint reports also. 
Can these issues be Office 365 tenant specific?

Comment: You can try this - access reports from portal.office.com and see it pulls the data or not?

Comment: Does the helped you moving forward?

Comment: Tnx everyone for the tips

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was a temporary issue with the specific O365 tenant.
Reports on the O365 portal didn't work as well for this route.

In this case you should contact MS support to check possible issues with GraphAPI on O365 instance.